# jquery (Autocomplete) показывает весь список вариантов вместо подбора по введенным буквам

Tags: jquery, java-ee, jsp

Есть страница JSP на которой используется jQuery (Autocomplete).
Подключил jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
<script type = "text/javascript">
         $(function() {
           $('#acInput').autocomplete({
             source: '/tags/'
           })
         }); 
</script>
```

данные получаем из Spring контроллера по ссылке `/tags/`.

также на странице есть поле ввода

```
<form:input  id="acInput" type="text" path="name" class="form-inline"
                placeholder='Name${name}' autofocus="true"></form:input>
```

ввожу данные в форму, но jQuery (Autocomplete) показывает весь список, а не сортирует по введенным данным.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделал сортировку в методе контроллера